# Why can't I launch my app from the shell?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying the helloworld App Engine [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld) for python 2.7.

When I try to launch my application from the shell (via `dev_appserver.py helloworld/`), I get this error:

```
INFO     2013-07-21 23:09:26,779 sdk_update_checker.py:244] Checking for updates to the SDK.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 182, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 178, in _run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 707, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 700, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 542, in start
    update_checker.check_for_updates(configuration)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/update_checker.py", line 91, in check_for_updates
    update_check.CheckForUpdates()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/sdk_update_checker.py", line 258, in CheckForUpdates
    runtime=runtime))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 394, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 412, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1207, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/fancy_urllib/__init__.py", line 383, in do_open
    url_error.reason.args[1])
fancy_urllib.InvalidCertificateException: Host appengine.google.com returned an invalid certificate (_ssl.c:503: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed): 
To learn more, see http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#rpcssl
```

However, when I launch an application created from the App Engine launcher GUI, my app runs fine locally: I can access the app via `http://localhost:8080/`.

Why can't I launch my application from the terminal?

I've checked out various other posts that recommended deleting a certain file that contained a certain certificate, but I feel that deleting a native file sounds sketch.

Comment: The file will get replaced with a fixed version on update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I can see what is going wrong but I don't know why it is going wrong.

The SDK is checking for updates and is failing to validated the identity of the Google server.

I would try these things:

- Make sure you have latest version installed: https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads
- Make sure date and time is set correctly on your machine (this could cause SSL certificate validation to fail)
- Delete (after taking a backup) google_appengine/lib/cacerts/urlfetch_cacerts.txt